# Calling SOAP UI test case from Java

Tags: java, soapui

I have a Test Suite for a REST web service created with two test cases.
As part of my testing, I want to create a Java code to call the test cases in this test suite. Is it possible to call a specific test case in SOAP UI from java.
Can anyone give some heads up on the code or any useful links where I can look for this.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: JUnit Test Suite?

Comment: @pringi : Its a simple SOAP UI test suite with 2 test cases. I just open the test suite and click on the run button to run the Test case.

Comment: Where is the REST web service that you have test cases for? Java web service?

Comment: @mechkov   Yes.  It is a java web service.  I am calling it from soap UI.  I am calling this from soap UI and have different test steps inside this test case to validate the data returned by the rest web service.  I want to call this test case( comprises of 8 test steps ) from Java code.

Comment: If there is soapui project is available, you can use soapui tool or its command line utility `testrunner` can be used. Why do you want to run in java without even having any idea?

Answer (score 1):

Use the following code to run SoapUI testcase from Java

```
WsdlProject project = new WsdlProject( "path of soapui-project.xml" ); 
TestSuite testSuite = project.getTestSuiteByName( "TestSuite Name" ); 
TestCase testCase = testSuite.getTestCaseByName( "TestCase Name" );
TestRunner runner = testCase.run( new PropertiesMap(), false );
```

But, Make sure that you are adding SoapUI libraries in your path